# Corrupt file download from Google Drive

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm having issues with the download process, it downloads, but the file downloaded is the same byte size: 108102 bytes; regardless of whether the actual file is smaller or bigger than this.

I'm able to upload a PDF file successfully and set its permissions to make it viewable by anyone with the link `https://drive.google.com/open?id=UNIQUE_ID_HERE`. Below is the function I use to download the file asynchronously:

```
    /// <summary>Downloads the media from the given URL.</summary>
    private async Task DownloadFile(DriveService service, string url)
    {
        var downloader = new MediaDownloader(service);
        downloader.ChunkSize = DownloadChunkSize;
        // add a delegate for the progress changed event for writing to console on changes
        downloader.ProgressChanged += Download_ProgressChanged;

        var fileName = DownloadDirectoryName + @"\cover_new.pdf";

        Console.WriteLine("Downloading file from link: {0}", url);

        using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            var progress = await downloader.DownloadAsync(url, fileStream);

            if (progress.Status == DownloadStatus.Completed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileName + " was downloaded successfully: " + progress.BytesDownloaded);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Download {0} was interrupted in the middle. Only {1} were downloaded. ", fileName, progress.BytesDownloaded);
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I'm able to open this file using the link successfully from a different browser without any credentials entered.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the contents of the file that was downloaded in a text editor. I suspect it is a HTML page that displays either an error message or some manner of a login screen.

Comment: @Phylyp , I opened the contents in Notepad++ and it's all html/javascript, but I don't see any access denied error, or anything of the like. I think it may be a login, but I can't say for sure. I renamed the file with a `.html` extension, but I'm unable to open it in a browser, it loads a blank page and the source is all there when I view it.

Comment: @Phylyp ,. I guess the first question should be whether I'm using the correct url for downloading. The DownloadAsync method requires url as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was incorrectly trying to download the file using a URL like: `https://drive.google.com/open?id=UNIQUE_ID_HERE`.

Changes I made to my method:

- The second parameter, `url`, is now a `file` object. I was passing the URL, but instead I should fetch the file using `service.Files.Get()` and using its Id.
- Rename the second parameter to fileToDownload, for clarity.
- Since I now have a file object `downloadfile` for the file I want to download, I can call its `DownloadAsync` method, sending it the filestream I already had.

The new code below:

```
    private async Task DownloadFile(DriveService service, Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File fileToDownload)
    {

        var downloader = new MediaDownloader(service);
        downloader.ChunkSize = DownloadChunkSize;
        // add a delegate for the progress changed event for writing to console on changes
        downloader.ProgressChanged += Download_ProgressChanged;

        var fileName = DownloadDirectoryName + @"\cover_new.pdf";

        var downloadfile = service.Files.Get(fileToDownload.Id);

        Console.WriteLine("Downloading file with id: {0}", fileToDownload);

        using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            var progress = await downloadfile.DownloadAsync(fileStream);

            if (progress.Status == DownloadStatus.Completed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileName + " was downloaded successfully: " + progress.BytesDownloaded);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Download {0} was interrupted in the middle. Only {1} were downloaded. ", fileName, progress.BytesDownloaded);
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: Happy you've solved it, and thanks for sharing the solution.